# Looking for QML specification

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, specification, qml

Where I can find the QML specification which is used for storing symbology information in QGIS?

I tried to Google it - but got no result.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing complicated about qml files, there just simple plain text XML files.

If you load one into notepad you'll see the layout is fairly straight forward.

You have a

```
<qgis>...</qgis>
```

tag that lists the version that created it among other things

Within this tag you have a

```
<transparencyLevelInt>
```

tag that holds transparency level info, a

```
<rendererer>
```

tag which appears to be instructions to the QGis rendering engine on how to draw the styles, and then within that renderer you have layer specific style information.

In my case because I saved some styles used for a categorised data set, I have a

```
<categories>
```

tag listing individual

```
<category>
```

tags that describe each category, and a

```
<symbols>
```

tag that includes a collection of

```
<symbol>
```

tags describing each symbol in the style set.

Further down it looks like there are entries for the layers name, label visibility, editing types and column names for the attributes in a layer.

It's all very straight forward to read, you just need to know how to pull apart the XML in the language you've chosen to use to manipulate them.

There's even a DTD address listed in the file, so loading the file into a DTD aware editor such as oxygeneXML should only allow you to enter legal tags in a legal order, however when I tried to access the DTD the web address was not found so you may want to check that one out further.

## Update Nov 2019

Apparently folks are still arguing about the DTD in my comments and in others.  The DTD that defines what the XML "**SHOULD**" look like can be found here

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/qgis.dtd

I've just checked the file and it's there, and a quick cursory glance over it looks like everything expected is present.

Comment: What you provide is not specification. I'm looking for document which describes all qml tags and their purposes, like OGC SLD standard.

Comment: Please read the last paragraph in my reply, starting : 'There's even a DTD.....' the DTD in question is embeded in the first line of the XML file, in XML file terms the DTD IS the specification.

Comment: Theres nothing complicated about a simple project file. But as you go deeper, you'll find the world of composers, labels and symbols, and it aint so easy anymore. There's no description or explanation you can use, just have to find out as you go. The DTD? Did you check the DTD? I get the answer- "The requested URL /qgis.dtd was not found on this server." You can check https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/qgis/qgis.dtd but thats not very useful either.

Comment: Again, please read the last paragraph in my reply for your answer :-)

Comment: As for the DTD on the contrary, it's very useful : http://www.xmlfiles.com/dtd/ a correctly formed DTD will tell you what you can and cannot put in an XML file created using it, in most cases when using a good editor it will also tell you the data type and (In the case of visual studio) will even give intellisense to show the compound types under a tag.  All that leaves you to do is a little bit of research as to what the tags and attributes hold, which in most cases is fairly self explanatory. Iv'e done it loads of times with different XML files.

Comment: And you've done it with qml aswell, i presume...

Comment: Yes I have.  I wrote a small .NET application to extract the style information used in a QGis project and import it into a web based control system used in-house for one of my clients, so their web maps looked the same as the projects their GIS team where using.

Comment: I've looked QGIS tracker and it looks like this DTD never existed. Ticket #4408 (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4408) for example. So my question is still open. I've also created a corresponding ticket in tracker.

Comment: Yea that was my worry, that said it's really not that complex, a weekends detective work and you should be able to figure the structure out yourself quite easily.

Comment: We will be happy to accept a DTD if someone could write one.

Comment: There is a DTD already available.  Take any QML file produced by QGis, look at the first line in the file, the DTD location is specified right there.

Comment: The svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/qgis/qgis.dtd  DTD does not appear to define a QML file.  `<!ELEMENT qgis (title, extent, projectlayers, mapunits) >`  appears to conflict with your statement that within a QGIS file you can have a `<transparencyLevelInt>` ~ you can't directly according to the DTD.  Looking at https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/blob/master/qgis2/osm_spatialite/osm_spatialite_googlemaps_lines.qml   There is no `edittypes` defined at all.  The DTD referenced in the example doesn't exist...

Comment: Well it existed when I posted this comment over 2 years ago!!!

Comment: Oh and for those nay sayers, who say hay!!! : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/qgis.dtd

Comment: If this answer is outdated then it should be updated.

Comment: hi poly, the git link i put above is the updated location of the dtd.  quite why it's not yet listed as the source in the qml file yet, only the qgis devs know. :-) feel free to make any changes you see fit.

Comment: I'm looking for the same documentation - a guide specifying the different components of a qml file.  Having some guidance on what components are essential (required) which ones are optional would be very useful too.  At the moment it's all trial and error. I think we could have nicer answers than getting us to look at the code and try and interpret it on our own.

Comment: @jberrio well I'm sure if you went and asked the qgis developers, if they would like your hand, writing a document, they would probably jump at the chance.  I'm not a member of the QGis dev team, never have been, so it's pointless telling me that one is needed, and better answers are warranted, I can only tell you what I know, and what I've found out over the years, all of which is written above.  Sorry, but that's just the way it is.  I think the QGis team have a requests page, you might want to put a request in there.

Comment: @shawty I'm not sure why you think my comment is towards you.  It's an open comment, and the normal way it works is: if you know the answer and can give a hand, you do; if you don't know the answer then there is no need for you to reply saying you don't know.  If you don't know, just let others who know reply?

Comment: @jberrio it just felt like you where yet another person, having a go at me, for not answering the question.  If you look at the previous comments, and the additions I've added to my answer, in the years since I posted it, I've had a number of people basically attempt to start a fight (Some of the comments have been removed) or get P****d at me, because they felt I was giving them the run around, I apologise if that was not your intention, but over the years this has been one of my more contentious posts, which I now honestly wish I'd never written.