# Different ways of saving color ramps in QGIS (xml, qml, csv), which should I use?

Tags: qgis, qml, color-ramp

I started to use QGIS for personal mapping as a hobby (specially for planning bike routes), and I notice there are more than one way to use color ramps.

1. There are styles, which can be saved and loaded, and may *contain* color ramps (that is, they *aren't* the color ramps themselves); When you save a style, the color ramp is saved as a `colorrampshader` tag in a `.qml` file;
2. There are the color ramps themselves, which consist of a table of value, RGBA color (editable via color picker), and label. This, when saved, generate a plain CSV file with `.txt` extension. An important difference seem to be the mapping of each color to a defined value (for example, to a given elevation) as opposed to a percentage from bottom to top;
3. There are `xml` files that apparently can be imported via Style Manager as described in [this blog post](http://anitagraser.com/2011/11/02/more-color-ramps-for-qgis/).

What I would like to know is: what is the preferred/canonical way to store a color ramp? Where can I find the specifications about `colorramp` and `colorrampshader` in their respective xml namespaces?

And where does QGIS store the predefined color ramp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS, the preferred/canonical way to store a color ramp is `QGIS layer styles (.qml)` files.

If you look inside the `qml` file using a simple text editor, you'll find there is nothing hard to understand.

`ColorRamp` example:

```
<colorramp type="gradient" name="[source]">
  <prop k="color1" v="247,251,255,255"/>
  <prop k="color2" v="8,48,107,255"/>
  <prop k="discrete" v="0"/>
  <prop k="stops" v="0.13;222,235,247,255:0.26;198,219,239,255:0.39;158,202,225,255:0.52;107,174,214,255:0.65;66,146,198,255:0.78;33,113,181,255:0.9;8,81,156,255"/>
</colorramp>
```

`ColorRampShader` example:

```
    <colorrampshader colorRampType="DISCRETE" clip="0">
      <item alpha="255" value="0.5" label="0.1 - 0.5" color="#aaffff"/>
      <item alpha="255" value="1" label="0.5 - 1" color="#00aaff"/>
      <item alpha="255" value="5" label="1 - 5" color="#0055ff"/>
      <item alpha="255" value="10" label="5 - 10" color="#00007f"/>
      <item alpha="255" value="15" label="10+" color="#00003c"/>
    </colorrampshader>
```

If you are looking for specifications, please, check **[this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34361/looking-for-qml-specification/34387)** answer.